# Редактирование содержимого сайта в WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu, меню

Хочу вставить меню сайта в область содержимого (не в `header.php`, не в `footer.php`, не в `sidebar.php`)

```css
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
</ul>
```

Хочу знать в какой файл нужно вставлять данный код.

Comment: там же вроде в визуальном редакторе из админки это можно сделать

Comment: Ни в какой файл. 1. Делай нормальное меню средствами ВП. 2. Объясни что такое "область содержимого" в твоем понимании?

Comment: @AndreyFreiz я хочу задать цвет пунктов меню сайта при наведении (и до наведения).

Comment: Вообще основная(контентная) часть находится и редактируется в файле index.php. Попробуйте там

Comment: @freeflash это уже нужно делать в `css` файле, делать `:hover` эффект, загугли что это, это очень просто

Comment: @Dmitry_allread_return не пори чушь. Лучше удали свой коммент.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай из этого html простой шорткод. Вставляй в нужную запись. Или вызов функции повесь на фильтр the_content. Или впиши в нужный шаблон твоей ВП темы. Больше по минимум информации не подсказать.